# Trying to create my first page using angular. Getting Expected Indentifier in javascript file

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4

I am trying to create my first angular page and tried following a video.  My solution in an MVC solution and I added Angular through "Manage Nuget Packages".

In this same solution I was using MVC and I was able to pull data from entity framework to fill a dropdown list.  So I decided to create a HTML page that shows an example of pulling data from EF using Angular.

The video shows creating a myapp.js

The first line is as follows:

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

An error stating Expected Identifier shows on the first square bracket and the program halts when trying to run at that spot.

There is also another error further down in the script but I am thinking I might have something configured wrong for angular.  I also get errors in my HTML anywhere I reference ng-'anything' but I read if I add data in front the errors go away.  I am not sure if this has anything to do with the errors in the javascript but I was hoping to find some help.

I am coming from a background in webforms and trying to get up to speed with newer technologies.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

FOLLOW UP:

The example video just showed making the Angular example in a standard HTML.  So that was how I created my example and I set the solution to start that page by default which seems to be working.  I am not sure if that has something to do with my issue, but here is my code:

```html
// MY ROUTE.CONFIG FILE
 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
 
namespace MVC_APP1
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
 
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp'), []);
myapp.controller('maincontroller', fuction($scope,$http)
{
    $http.get('/Company/Index').then(function=(response) {
        $scope.companies=response.data;
    })
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/myapp.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng.app="myapp">
    <div data-ng-controller="maincontroller">
        <select data-ng-model="s" data-ng-options="Company.Company_Key as Company.Company_Name for Company in companies"></select>
       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anything syntactically wrong with that one line of code.

Comment: You'll need to show your `index.cshtml` to get a better understanding of how your MVC project is setup and how you are trying to load Angular. Also your route config as well as the home controller or equivalent.

Comment: I added code above.  Thank you for your responses.  I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: @jack: The line of code in what you added doesn't match the line of code in the description you originally gave.  There's a typo in the code.

Comment: I think I need glasses.  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in the supplied code example:

1. The declaration of 'myapp' is prematurely closed with:

   `var myapp = angular.module('myapp'), []);`

   and should be updated to:

   `var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);`
2. The call out to `$http` should declare a function, not attempt to set 'function' to a value

   `$http.get('/Company/Index').then(function=(response) {
       $scope.companies=response.data;
   })`

   should update to:

   `$http.get('/Company/Index').then(function(response) {
       $scope.companies=response.data;
   });`